# OnConnectedToServer not being called [UNET]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have the following simple class extending Networkbehaviour. I need to wait for a connection to server in order to call a [Command] funtcion.

Any UNET or multiplayer experts able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class KeepClientConnected : NetworkBehaviour {

    public int pingInterval = 30;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }

    void Start(){

    }

    void OnDisconnectedFromServer(NetworkDisconnection info)
    {
        if (Network.isServer)
            Debug.Log("Local server connection disconnected");
        else
            if (info == NetworkDisconnection.LostConnection)
            Debug.Log("Lost connection to the server");
        else
            Debug.Log("Successfully diconnected from the server");
    }


    private void OnConnectedToServer()
    {
        Debug.Log("0 ASSERT OnConnectedToServer");
        StartCoroutine(myCoRoutine());
    }

    [Command]
    void Cmd_KeepConnection()
    {
        Debug.Log("2 ASSERT calling KeepConnection on Server");
    }

    IEnumerator myCoRoutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Cmd_KeepConnection();
            Debug.Log("1 ASSERT calling KeepConnection on Server");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used OnConnectedToServer but I can give you a couple of alternatives.

1. Make a Player. Have this network behavior exist on that player. The player will only get created once the client is connected.
2. Extend NetworkManager and override OnStartClient while making sure to still call base.OnStartClient.   In this method you can be sure that the client is started and ready as it passes a reference to the client to you.

As a side note I used the following code in my player's Update method:

```
            if (KeepAlive)
            {
                LastPing += Time.deltaTime;
                if (LastPing > 10)
                {

                    LastPing = 0;
                    CmdPing();
                }
            }
```